# jquery children bug? why not all objects in children collection

Tags: jquery, children

here is 2 inputs in form, why all text are pink color, but input[name2] are black?
why input[name2] are not in children() collection??

```
<form>
<div>Form is surrounded by the green border.

    <label for="name">Child of form:</label>
    <input name="name" id="name" value="123" />

    <div>
       <label for="name2">Child of form in div:</label>
       <input name="name2" id="name2" value="1234" />
    </div>

</form>

<script>
$( "form").children().css( "color", "pink" );
$( "form").children("div").css( "color", "red" );
</script>
```

Comment: The form only has one child, the first `<div>`. The first `<input>` is a grandchild, the second one is a great-grandchild.

Comment: BTW, you're missing a `</div>` before `</form>`

Comment: @Barmar why doesn't the input inherit the color style from the parent?

Comment: It should. Maybe you have other CSS that's overriding it.

Comment: @Barmar no... http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6TZtp/1/

Comment: @Barmar but [this](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6TZtp/2/) works

Comment: Looks like the browser has default CSS for `<input>` elements.

Comment: To get all descendant elements of the form, you would use `$("form").find("*")`.

Answer (score 1):

The input inside the div is not a child of the form. `.children()` only gets direct children. Also, inputs do not inherit styles from their parent. If you want them all to be pink just do:

```
$('form input').css('color', 'pink');
```

Comment: You can just do `$('form input').css('color', 'pink')`.

Comment: or $('form input').css('color', 'inherit')

Answer (score 0):

.children() only gets direct children.

> Get the children of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

```
$( "form").children("div").css( "color", "red" );
```

---

```
<form>
    <div>Form is surrounded by the green border.//children
        <label for="name">Child of form:</label>//grand children
        <input name="name" id="name" value="123" />//grand children
        <div>//grand children
            <label for="name2">Child of form in div:</label>//grand grand children
            <input name="name2" id="name2" value="1234" />// grand grand children
        </div>
</form>
```

---

Use [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
$('form').find('input').css('color', 'pink');
```

Comment: You're off by one generation from the `<form>`.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery children() method returns direct children of the element, not children of it's children also. So in your code above, the elements within the 2nd div would not be selected.

To target those, try

```
$( "form").children("div").children().css( "color", "red" );
```